# Converting timestamp with milliseconds to datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

ALL,

I'm trying to get a statistical data of the file. Doing so gives me following:

```
atime - datetime timestamp representation
atime_nano - nano-seconds resolution in addition to a_time.
```

What I'd like to do is to convert atime.atime_nano to a datetime variable in Python.

So if I have:

```
atime = 1092847621L
atime_nano = 7100000L
```

I'd like to convert it to the datetime object in python that will have correct date with the milliseconds.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: what's the problem? `datetime` should be able to handle milliseconds just fine.

Comment: @msvalkon, the problem is the correct syntax. Is datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(atime.atime_nano) will work? Thank you.

Comment: No, it will not. First of all, nanoseconds and milliseconds are not the same thing. Second, you have to `long` variables, you cannot say `atime.atime_nano`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datetimes can have microseconds (1 microsecond = 1000 nanoseconds)
You can do the following for your example:

```
   dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(1092847621L).replace(microsecond = 7100000L/1000)
```

Comment: `fromtimestamp()` tries to return a naive datetime object in local timezone. The result maybe ambiguous and wrong in some cases. Use UTC timezone instead: `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1092847621L).replace(microsecond=int(7100000L * 1e-3 + .5))`